# Centering a DIV Element in CSS

Tags: css, html

I want to center a Div element in CSS. I have tried everything I found. Nothing seems to work?
I've checked my CSS with W3C's validator. No errors. I am clueless. This is my latest attempt.

```css
body {
   background: url(loginbg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    float: left; 
    width: 230px; 
    padding: 15px 5px 5px 5px; 
    margin-top: 5px; 
    margin-left: 3px; 
    border: 1px solid #999999;  
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;     
}


#submit_img, #sumbit_button {
   cursor: pointer;
   margin:0 auto;
}

#loginarea {
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

mY HTMl code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="login.css">
<title>
Login
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loginarea" class="loginarea">
<div id="username_box">
<input type="text" id="username" value="Username">
</div> <div id="password_box">
<br><br><br><br>
<input type="password" id="password" value="Password">
</div>
    <br><br><bR>
    <button id="sumbit_button" style="border: 0; background: transparent;">
        <img src="loginbutton.png" width="150" height: "50" id="sumbit_img">
     </button>
    <br>
 </div>
<div id="footer" class="footer">
    Copyright 2013 company name| CraftManager 1.2 | Credits
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it the footer blocking the centering?

---

Current Status:

I have set a width on the div , and "centered" the margins. It makes a difference, though it isn't truly centered.

Comment: The code thing was screwed up. Sorry!

Comment: Just paste in the code, select all the code then press Ctrl+K

Comment: I assume `#loginarea` is what you're trying to center?

Comment: Where is your HTML markup? `;)`

Comment: yep it is what i am centering

Comment: There are no `div` styles in the css

Comment: Showing the html of how it's used and what's around it might be good too.

Comment: umm too long for a comment

Comment: @Algo If you need to add content to respond to a comment/question, you can edit your original question.

Comment: Do you think the footer is blocking it?

Comment: Btw. ```id="sumbit_img"``` should rather be ```id="submit_img"```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this before, code isn't handy so I googled it. 
http://www.dzone.com/snippets/dead-centre-div may help.

I don't know why it won't let you do so by doing 50% from the left with css and 50% from the top.

Are you interested in centering it both vertically and horizontally?

that's what I was interested in, and my own results and success rate even depended on the size of the div.

Comment: Ah ha! Why haven't I seen this answer before? Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By default a `<div>` element fills 100% of parent element's width. If you want to center it, then the first thing you have to do is make it less than 100% wide.

So set a width on the div, 200px or something, and then you can set `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`

```
#loginarea {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* top/bottom: 0 margin. left/right: auto margin */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LzgpW/

Comment: @Algo Your HTML is correct but you are missing `width: 200px;` on `#loginarea`. Here http://jsfiddle.net/LzgpW/

Comment: I have a set width, it is the only div on the page, and i set the margins. Not working?

Comment: @Algo where did you set the width? I am looking at the code you posted and there is no width on the div.

Comment: Although it isn't really related, try to add ```overflow:hidden;``` to ```#loginarea```. It clears the inner floats. See http://jsfiddle.net/DW6XT/

Comment: @Algo width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; will definitely work unless you are doing something else that breaks it. Unless you show us the code you're actually using we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

try set

```
   margin-left: auto ;
   margin-right: auto ;
```

for more details check [here](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/center-div-block.shtml)

Comment: check whether you have set the width

Answer (score 0):

`auto` margins only work when the element to center has a "known" size. So, if you want `#loginarea` to be centered, you need to give it a width:

```
#loginarea {
    width:30em; /* can be any relative or fixed size, like 200px or 30% */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Example:** jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XBCVc/1/

Comment: It changes it a little, but not centered.

Comment: @Algo It should be, unless you have it inside of another element that has some less-than-100% width.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the loginarea div is not closed. Please double check that.

Comment: Nope, it is closed. I'll run it through w3c though.

Comment: Did you added a width to loginarea as well? You may use only the ID without the class in opening tag of loginarea.